# File Explorer not working

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

my file explorer doesn't work, when I click on a video to watch it, the whole explorer freezes and it says "not responding", it does with google sometimes, and my mouse turns into that blue circle meaning loading. I can't even drop videos into my video editor because as soon as I do the explorer does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, and pull down Maintenance. You will likely see multiple "Explorer stopped working" errors.

I have seen this myself.

Do a Windows 10 Repair Install to correct this.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on Download (not the first Upgrade) Button. Download the ISO to a USB Key and then run Setup.exe to launch.

Allow it to complete (download and install time) and Windows Explorer should work.

Repair Install (using the Keep Everything option), leaves everything as it was.

Note:  Repair Install will not correct a damaged Windows User Profile  (it cannot). You may wish to try a test Windows User Profile to see if Windows Explorer works in a new user Profile.

Comment: will this reset the hard disk

Comment: No, it will not reset the hard drive. I did amplify my answer above.